# Maven Fatal Error on struts2-archetype-blank

Tags: java, maven, struts2

I'm trying to start a new struts 2 project using maven (struts2 blank archetype)
The code below runs and generates the project along with its pom.xml

```
D:\Dev\IndigoWS>mvn archetype:generate -B DgroupId=com.proj.core -DartifactId=MyStruts2Blank -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-ar
chetype-blank -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.1
```

with the following stacktrace from the terminal.

```
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [archetype:generate] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing archetype:generate
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] [archetype:generate {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[INFO] Archetype repository missing. Using the one from [org.apache.struts:strut
s2-archetype-blank:2.2.3] found in catalog remote
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but whenever I try to convert it into an eclipse project using the command

`mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=1.5`

I encountered the fatal error below

> D:\Dev\MyWorkspace>cd MyStruts2Blank
>
> D:\Dev\MyWorkspace\MyStruts2Blank>mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=1.5
>
> [INFO] Scanning for projects... 
>   [INFO]--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
>   [ERROR] FATAL ERROR
>   [INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
>   [INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).
>
> Project ID: com.proj.core:MyStruts2Blank POM Location:
>   D:\Dev\MyWorkspace\MyStruts2Blank\pom.xml

the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.royj.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyStruts2Blank</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Struts 2 Blank Webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <struts2.version>${project.version}</struts2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.21</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <scanTargets>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/resources/struts.xml</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/resources/example.xml</scanTarget>
                    </scanTargets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the maven version

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 03:16:01+0800)
Java version: 1.6.0_24
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp" version: "5.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"
```

What do I need to do to fix this and successfully generate a struts 2 blank archetype.  I can successfully create a starter archetype for struts 2 using maven but with no success for the blank archetype.  Is the blank archetype no longer available? By the way I am using **Eclipse Indigo Version: Indigo , Release Build id: 20110615-0604**
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: have you gone through this http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/struts-2-blank-archetype.html?

Comment: Which eclipse version, which Maven version ? Can you post the POM?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi and I have edited my question and included the pom.xml by the way I am using Eclipse Indigo 

Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110615-0604

Comment: @khmarbaise and I have edited my question and included the pom.xml by the way I am using Eclipse Indigo Version: Indigo Release Build id: 20110615-0604

Comment: @royjavelosa: as suggest in the answer first thing is missing `project.version` and i will suggest you to use maven standalone version

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I upvoted your comment.  For others who might read this question I just want to inform you that using the link Umesh gave would help to successfully create a blank struts 2 archetype with maven.  To resolve the FATAL ERROR from the scenario follow the instructions from the accepted answer in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first i have to say don't use mvn eclipse:eclipse in relationship with Eclipse Indigo anymore, cause you have m2e as part of Indigo furthermore install m2e wtp plugin via Eclipse Marketplace. Where is your project.version defined, cause you are using it in relationship with your struts version but in your pom you didn't define any version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.royj.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyStruts2Blank</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Struts 2 Blank Webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <struts2.version>2.3.1.2</struts2.version>
    </properties>
...
</project>
```

Apart from that i would suggest to upgrade to Maven 3.0.3 cause Eclipse Indigo uses a Maven 3. embedded.

Comment: Just bothers me why eclipse:eclipse causes problems if Indigo adapted m2e for better maven integration, why did they not make it cohesive since their purpose is integrating maven with your projects.    Even if Eclipse Indigo uses an embedded maven 3 shouldn't it be backwards compatible?

Comment: Additional info for others who lost their sanity.
http://grumpyapache.blogspot.com/2011/08/mess-that-is-m2e-connectors.html

Comment: @royjavelosa The is not problem with backwars compatibility. Maven 3 is a replacement for Maven 2.2.1 only in areas with the site generation there are some issue to be aware of.